# SQL query how to match 3 out of 4 results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have searched a number of different items but I have not found any answers. Chances are I just don't know how to word this correctly.

Anyway, I have set up a system in PHP/SQL to allow instantaneous scanning of thousands of results. Each data entry has 4 numbers, and it can easily scan for entries that match all 4 of these numbers. What I am trying to achieve is to have the script search the database for entries that match exactly 3 out of the 4 entries with the other being incorrect, kind of like a lottery.

```
For example, we have the entries:
Steve - 1, 4, 10, 13
Bill - 3, 4, 10, 13
Tom - 1, 17, 20, 39
Jill - 1, 4, 13, 21
Jane - 5, 10, 13, 18
```

Now, I would scan based on the results 1, 4, 10, 13, and would like to return the following results, as these matched 3 of the 4 entries:

```
Bill - 3, 4, 10, 13
Jill - 1, 4, 13, 21
```

How would I achieve this?

Many thanks

EDIT: Sorry yes the table has the structure
    Name - Number1 - Number2 - Number3 - Number4

So yes, stored as separate fields

Comment: Some table info? Field names? What you did try? etc...

Comment: Show us some schema. Are these strings? I.e., is there a single row for "Steve" with "1,4,10,13" or are the values stored as separate rows in another table related to the people?

Comment: How about doing the post processing on the php side?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by counting the matches and setting this equal to 3:

```
select t.*
from t
where (val1 in (1, 4, 10, 13) +
       val2 in (1, 4, 10, 13) +
       val3 in (1, 4, 10, 13) +
       val4 in (1, 4, 10, 13)
      ) = 3;
```

In MySQL a TRUE boolean expression evaluates to `1`.  You can add these together to get the number of matches.